# wpdb_prepare with multiple or condition

Tags: database, mysql, sql, wpdb

I want to execute a query like this:

```
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * ... from ... WHERE ( post_title LIKE '%%%s%%' or post_content LIKE '%%%s%%' )..., $string );
```

If I do the query with only one condition it works:

```
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * ... from ... WHERE ( post_title LIKE '%%%s%%' )..., $string );
```

What is the error in my first query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your first partial code be this partial code:

```
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * ... from ... WHERE ( post_title LIKE '%%%s%%' or post_content LIKE '%%%s%%' )..., $string, $string );
```

You have to have to pass the same number of arguments into the query as you specify (with %s) in it.

Comment: Yep. That makes sense. It works now... THX

Answer (score 1):

```
$like = '%'. $wpdb->esc_like($searchExpression) . '%';   

$sql_content =  $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE (     post_title LIKE '%%%s%%' or post_content LIKE '%%%s%%' )", $like, $like );
$post_id = $wpdb->get_var($sql_content);
```

this worked from
credits user998163